# How to use an Apple Wireless Keyboard with Windows Phone Emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

Normally you just hit Page Up or the Pause/Break key but the Apple Wireless Keyboard doesn't have these keys.  Is there a way I can input keystrokes into the Windows Phone Emulator from my Apple Wireless Keyboard?

Comment: Do not use Apple stuff for Microsoft development :)

Comment: Why not? Bootcamp works beautifully. I've even given WP7 user group talks/demos on my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to enter text in the emulator?

Press Function-Escape. It works on my MacBook Pro keyboard.